# Dynamic tableview cells creation

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have to make a tableview with different cells in it. I have three preferences and the table depends on them. There may be 6 different tableviews - 1 cell, 1cell and 3cell, no cell, 2 cell and 3 cell and so on, this depends on preferences

That's the best way to do this?

Maybe someone knows good example, or tutorial on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make just one `UITableView` with different sections.

Based on your section id you may be returning different cell in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

`indexPath` contains `row` & `section` values.

Also you might return different number of rows in a section with:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
//pass value to numper of cells;
return 4 (or) 2;
}

//use this to add cell 
[tableview reloadData];
```